# Removing Firestore snapshot listener inside of LiveData-returning function

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to optimise the performances in my app and I noticed that I do not remove Firestore listeners from my repository.

My repository has a number of functions that return a `LiveData`, that is then observed via Transformations from `ViewModels` and then the views.

One-time operations work absolutely fine (upload, delete etc.) but permanent listeners don't get garbage collected when the activity finishes.

Right now the function inside the repository looks like this:

```
// [...]
class Repository {   
  // [...]
  fun retrieveCode() {
  val observable = MutableLiveData<Code>()
  val reference = 
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(/**/).document(/**/)

  reference
    .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception -> 
      if(exception != null) {
        observable.value = null
      }

      if(snapshot != null {
        observable.value = snapshot.//[convert to object]
      }
   }

   return observable
  }
}
```

I found a workaround which is to create a custom `LiveData` object that handles the listener removal when it becomes inactive, like this:

```
class CodeLiveData(private val reference: DocumentReference): 
  LiveData<Code>(), EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>{
  private var registration: ListenerRegistration? = null

  override fun onEvent(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot?, 
    exception: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    if(exception != null) {
      this.value = null
    }

    if(snapshot != null) {
      this.value = snapshot.//[convert to object]
    }
  }

  override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    registration = reference.addSnapshotListener(this)
  }

  override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    registration?.remove()
  }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem without creating a custom class, but rather by improving a function similar to the first example?

Thanks,

Emilio

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant code samples rather than just linking to them.

Comment: Edited the main post, should be fine now

Comment: Creating a LiveData subclass is the right thing to do, since it understands when clients are observing.  Why are you against it?

Comment: See also my blog, it is exactly what I recommend: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I'll go with the LiveData subclass then. I was not sure whether or not it was the best approach because all of the others operations (upload, delete, etc.) were performed through simple MutableLiveDatas, but I guess it makes sense for a continuously observed source to have its own LiveData subclass. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways in which you can achieve this. The first one would be to stop listening for changes and this can be done in your `onStop()` function by calling `remove()` function on your `ListenerRegistration` object like this:

```
if (registration != null) {
    registration.remove();
}
```

The approach would be to you pass your activity as the first argument in the `addSnapshotListener()` function, so Firestore can clean up the listeners automatically when the activity is stopped.

```
var registration = dataDocumentReference
        .addSnapshotListener(yourActivity, listener)
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of them are possible because the listener is created inside a Repository which does not have access to an Activity or its lifecycle methods.

Comment: But the activity can have access to the function inside the class so you can pass your activity when creating the `registration` object.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you wrote, are you suggesting I pass the activity as a parameter for the function inside the repository? I'm pretty sure that would result in a severe memory leak and break the separation of the layers.

Comment: There are seven overloaded functions of`addSnapshotListener()`. I'm reffering to this **[public ListenerRegistration addSnapshotListener (Activity activity, EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> listener)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E))**.

Comment: I actually used Doug Stevenson's response because it went better with my architecture. Thanks for your advice though, I'm sure it would have worked just as fine on another architecture.